# Do the cookies already work while you just log in on the login screen of a Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, personal-data, cookies

Do the cookies already work while (that is, right before) you log in?

At the point in time when it shows you the "Your privacy" box with the three cookie buttons to choose from,

[image]

I want to know whether it will use "Accept all cookies" when I just click "Log in"

[image]

instead of clicking one of those three cookie buttons ("Accept all cookies", Necessary cookies only", "Customize settings").

If you are logged out, and you log in with your username (or just with the "Log in" button if you have already logged in on another open website), I wonder whether the cookies already work for that "parent" website on that you were not logged in.

In other words:

What is clear to me is that as soon as you log in, it takes the cookie settings of the login. It is unclear to me whether the cookies of "right before the login" will work as "Accept all cookies" if I do not click something else.

Say you want to always allow nothing more than the necessary cookies. Would you then need to at first click on "Necessary cookies only" or "Customize settings", and afterwards log in? Or does the login replace the cookie settings right away, before any cookie data was fetched?

Comment: Once a question is answered, you shouldn't edit the question in a way that invalidates existing answers.

Comment: @KevinB The "question in clearer words" did not change the question. The answer does not answer the question at hand, whether you rolled it back to rev 3 or not. The given answer has never answered the question, and I have made that clear rightaway in the remarks and have not accepted it since then. That is why I will now rollback to my last edit.

Comment: I mean, simply not accepting an answer doesn't give users the right to just keep changing their question on answerers.

Comment: @KevinB It is not a change of the question. I understand it is too much to read and would be a waste of time if you did so, but what I put in there is nothing than the same question in other words. No change of the question.

Comment: Besides, what is the point of editing this question into a duplicate of the new one you just asked? all while claiming the one you just asked isn't a duplicate of this one?

Comment: @KevinB It is not a duplicate. This is about the login session, not about the cookies that pop up while you are already logged in. I have made that clear at the end of the other question. For the other readers, this is about [Without having logged out before: which cookies are saved if I do not click on any button of that cookie settings window and just go on?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427840/11154841).

Comment: No? your edit(s) clearly indicate you want the question to be what cookies are created when no choice has been made on the cookie popup... which is exactly what your other question is asking. The answer literally shows you what cookies are being created.

Comment: @KevinB No, this is here about being logged out and when you are then right before the next click on "Login". I want to know whether in that tiny second, all cookies are already saved. So that I have to click on "Necessary cookies only" before I click on "Login" if I want to avoid "Accept all cookies" in the logout session.

Comment: There's no difference between logged in or logged out... why would there be? being logged in doesn't change your cookie popup choice or lack thereof.

Comment: @KevinB I thought the cookies would be saved for the logged-in account in another way than for an anonymous logout, as if it were two websites so-to-speak.

Comment: No, most definitely not. They're stored per device. that's how cookies work!

Comment: @KevinB The strange thing is that I doubt that I would also have to click that if I was logged in all the time. But I might be wrong with that. Which would then be an answer to this question: I have to click that since my DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials extension or the like has removed the cookies (logged in or logged out does not matter). If I did not click any button of that window, but instead on "Login", it would be mutual consent to "Accept all cookies". That would mean that I should always click on "Necessary cookies only" if I had cookie paranoia. I would accept such an answer.

Comment: the cookies that you need to maintain a logged in session are considered "necessary". You can tell by the fact that you can login.

Comment: Why would you assume not making a choice goes with "Allow all"? Wouldn't an answer demonstrating that isn't the case answer your question?

Comment: @KevinB On most websites, clicking on nothing means consent. As to your remark before: you mean that it fills my user and password then? But I do not mean that login page. I mean a question page where you see the login button at the top right. I still grab from your remarks here that the cookie settings are just forgotten and need to be set again. If I click on "Login", it will take the default of that pop up, which is likely "Accept all cookies", and it will not ask for any cookie settings after the login since it takes over the mutual consent from the logout session before.

Comment: You can tell by looking at your cookies that that obviously isn’t the case. The answer below even did that for you, 9 months ago.

Comment: @KevinB I do not know how to do that (and mainly: how I could be sure about that with that little knowledge in cookies). That is what I was asking for. Also, I highly doubt that the default is "Necessary cookies only". The default on most websites is to accept all cookies. Only a few mainly public service sites do it the other way round.

Comment: I don’t know what evidence would convince you if 1: you can’t look for yourself and 2: you don’t trust an answer that shows you *exactly* what cookies are created and when.

Comment: @KevinB I trust it, but it does not answer the question. "Yes, what you choose is stored, without the need to log in, and it is remembered outside of your login session." So what happens with the cookies *inside* my login session? Will they take over the "Accept all cookies" default from the logout session before? Or will they remember that I chose "Necessary cookies only" at my last login? (answer: No - since cookies do not depend on the account) And will in that tiny second that I change to the login the consent of the default be passed if I do not click on the pop up? Yes. Which default?

Comment: No.. because being logged in is irrelevant to what cookie choice you have made. Whether or not you own a car is also irrelevant to whether or not you’ve made a cookie choice.

Comment: @KevinB That is what I meant with "No - since cookies do not depend on the account". I guess you mean to make that clearer only. Well, then it all comes down to that last question: what is the default if I do not click on anything in that logout session? Is it what I had before ("Necessary cookies only" - but how should it know that if the cookie settings are forgotten?), or is it a reset so that it switches to "Accept all cookies"?

Comment: You can tell by the fact that ga cookies are not set until you allow all that only necessary cookies are allowed until you allow all. The answer clearly demonstrates this.

Comment: @KevinB If that is so. You mean to see that from the cookie insight of the answer below at ".ga"? The answer is about the logout session. I need the same cookie overview from a login session after having skipped that pop up window. The answer below does not show that.

Comment: ***Being logged in is irrelevant to whether or not you have allowed all cookies.*** you can tell by the fact that you still get the popup while logged in, without needing to know how to look at the cookies yourself.

Comment: I mean if you skip the pop up window = you do not click any of those buttons and instead click on "Login". The pop up does not show up anymore if you click "Login". Yet, the pop up stays on every new site if you stay logged out and skip the pop up. The "Login" must play a role, it must know the cookie settings after the login. And I guess that these settings will be the default since you skipped the cookie pop up. And that could mean that after the login, without having chosen a cookie setting from that pop up, you are in the default, which could be "Accept all cookies". No proof below.

Comment: That is [demonstrably false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdeZb.png).

Comment: Hum, strange conversation for the last 4h, (I strongly agree with KevinB's stance), Cookies Monitoring is fairly easy to debug, @OP can't you redo yourself the Testing from Cerbrus' Answer/Results if you don't trust it/those...? This is  _very basic Web-computing_ knowledge/understanding about using a Browser and the _Internet_...

Comment: _" The default on most websites is to accept all cookies."_ OP, that is ___blatantly false___ and ___illegal___ to do. It's clear that you have a ___very___ limited understanding of how cookies work, so how about instead of assuming all kinds of nonsense, you actually listen to the people that are explaining to you how they work?

Comment: @Cerbrus It is not illegal, or if it is, I guess it is still happening (and this is also not about being illegal or not, but just to see, what happens, since I trust SE to go with the GDPR and this is not a question on law), I see this quite often: if you do not click on the cookie settings, we guess from this that you agree to "all cookies". I saw this also in recruiting platforms in GDPR Europe, they often ask you: if you do not do anything, we keep your CV. Thus, giving consent can be done mutually.

Comment: @questionto42 it **is** illegal (at least it violates GDPR). GDPR requires consent to be unambiguous consenting to cookies by inaction isn't unambiguous.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you load https://stackoverflow.com in an incognito window, *one* cookie (`prov`) is set:

[image]
(No idea what that is)

Then, immediately when you consent to cookies, two ore more cookies are added:

Only necessary:
[image]

All cookies:
[image]

(note that the `prov` cookie doesn't normally change values, I had to wipe cookies for the screenshots)

So, long story short:

Yes, what you choose is stored, without the need to log in, and it is remembered outside of your login session.

And no, logging in does not do *anything* with cookie consent.