# Without having logged out before: which cookies are saved if I do not click on any button of that cookie settings window and just go on?

Tags: support, personal-data, cookies

Whenever I change places or computers and without having logged out, staying in the same Firefox account, I am asked for cookie settings:

[image]

I guess from this that IP address and place get saved anyway.

##### DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials seems to lead to the many pop ups

From the remarks I know now that it is likely my Firefox "DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials" extension that leads to the many pop ups. That extension blocks Facebook and Google and some other companies from loading tracking information and could clear the settings on the device after the session. Still it is clear that the settings pop up window depends on changing the device or place, and if I change the device and it asks me again even if I had already clicked on the cookie settings on that device before, that shows that the device is stored at Stack Exchange and checked against the new device coming in. Same with place.

The DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials extension seems to forget my settings. I have to click again and again on "Necessary cookies only" as soon as I open the platform at another place or machine.

##### My guess: "Accept all cookies" is the default and will be mutually agreed upon if you do not click

I guess that "Necessary cookies only" is not the default. I get the "Necessary cookies" only if I click the button, else, I guess that it will be "Accept all cookies". Yet, this is just a *guess*. I do not know this for sure. Therefore the question as follows.

To those who think this would be illegal, check https://medium.com/ that takes your mutual consent from just surfing it, no click needed:

[image]

> To make Medium work, we log user data. By using Medium, you agree to our Privacy Policy, including cookie policy.

I wonder whether there is any mutual consent to a default if you go on surfing without a click on a cookie settings choice on Stack Exchange, and which default that would be.

##### Question

What happens if I do not click on any cookie settings button and just go on? Will it be mutual consent to "Accept all cookies" if I just go on even if I have often enough clicked on "Necessary cookies only"?

##### Technical background

I know the technical background of the cookie settings from [Do the cookies already work while you just log in on the login screen of a Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/423818/11154841), and yet, the answer there does not fully answer my question.

##### Is this question here a duplicate?

In my eyes, the question there, [Do the cookies already work while you just log in on the login screen of a Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/423818/11154841), is not a duplicate to this one here, at least not a full duplicate: it overlaps with the question here, right, but it is one step further, it asks what happens if you are logged out and you click on login instead of clicking on the cookie buttons and logging in after that. This question instead asks what happens if you are already logged in and do not click on the cookie buttons and go on surfing the page.

Comment: Cookies are device specific, if you are changing device, then yes, you will need to (re)accept them. That's not a conspiracy, that's expected behaviour.

Comment: @ThomA The cookie settings pop up even if you just switch places while you stay on the same device, that is why I ask the question. That they change with the machine is not that astonishing, right.

Comment: That's not what you state in the question: *"Whenever I change places or computers,"*

Comment: I mean, presumably, the necessary cookies are necessary for the site to function. so if the site is functioning you can similarly assume they are being used, if they are necessary for your usage. You can always go to the dev tools yourself to see what cookies currently exist for your browsing session.

Comment: @questionto42 Perhaps because you said "Whenever I change ... computers, I am asked for cookie settings." - Yes, that's definitely intended functionality...

Comment: @Nickistired Whenever I was on one device and open another that should already know my settings from my clicks beforehand on that same device, it will also ask me for a click since it knows there that I changed places, I guess, or it knows my IP. If that is hard to grab, think of changing places only, since that is the most astonishing to me. I click on "necessary cookies" almost every day since I change places a lot, on the same device, without having opened another device in the meantime.

Comment: Cookies aren't IP based, they are device based. Perhaps you have an extension, or browser setting, that deletes your cookies when you close your browser. Perhaps you're in private browsing, and didn't notice.

Comment: @ThomA Laptop and desktop pc. I rarely use the desktop pc. And I think it is the same policy. The places or IP change, then it asks. Thus, the cookies are saved on the device, but Stack Exchange seems to know in their databases that the device or place has changed (at my desktop pc, it can only be the machine that has changed since I am on the same desktop pc for long and clicked on the settings there too often, it should know them, but as soon as I work on my laptop and switch back to the desktop pc, it will ask).

Comment: @ThomA I am not in private browsing. It could be an extension, I have Firefox with the "DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials" extension. I will swich it off and check the cookie popups for some days.

Comment: I suspect that is the *real* problem; that extension has cookie-related features. (I don't have the extension installed, but if a passing user that does might share more insight.)

Comment: @ThomA It could be *the* helpful remark here, yes. I will check this, I will come back to this question after some time.

Comment: @ThomA Since it is too likely that the extension leads to the many pop ups, I have already put that in the question. Now the main question is still not answered: what is saved when I do not click on anything of that pop up? All cookies or just necessary cookies?

Comment: There is an entire section on [Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/cookie-policy) in the [Privacy Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy).

Comment: Is your question about preventing the cookie popup from showing up or is it about what the title says? All that talk about your extensions might be noise if we go by the title.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat The extension is just noise, still good to know though, since the many pop ups made me ask this question here in the end. If I was not asked every day, I would not spend the time on this. My question is: "What happens if I do not click on any cookie settings button and just go on? Will it be mutual consent to "Accept all cookies" if I just go on even if I have often enough clicked on "Necessary cookies only"?"

Comment: What you clicked previously is irrelevant if the popup is showing up, given clearly your choice is no longer saved.

Comment: @KevinB That sounds right. Why should it ask. The settings are clearly forgotten. And my guess is likely right that it saves all cookies by default if I do not click on any cookie button at all. That would mean that if I have such an extension, I might have to click on that again and again if I do not want to be tracked further than the necessary cookies (place, device, IP, ...). If I do not click anything, the cookies will save the browser history and the like, or whatever all cookies will mean.

Comment: it should ask because it needs your permission for the non-necessary cookies. I don't get why this is such a hard to understand topic. "necessary" does have a definition.

Comment: Whether or not you have logged in at any point in the past has no effect on what choosing or not choosing does.

Comment: [Global Privacy Control](https://globalprivacycontrol.org/) seems to be respected by SE, when I go to SO in an incognito window the consent popup doesn't show, and the consent cookie notes that I have GPC enabled. It's an easy option if you want to explicitly reject tracking cookies on SE and some other sites, though it can be a pain to enable depending on the browser.

Comment: @KevinB I highly doubt that the default is "Necessary cookies only". The default on most websites is to accept all cookies. Only a few mainly public service sites do it the other way round.

Comment: @questionto42 depending on your locality, accept all by default would likely be against the law. The EU, for example, has quite strict rules.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do the cookies already work while you are logged out on a question site, see the cookie pop up but click "Login" instead?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423817/do-the-cookies-already-work-while-you-are-logged-out-on-a-question-site-see-the)

Comment: @ThomA As a US-based company and US-hosted site Stack Exchange doesn't really have to comply with or care about EU rules, FWIW. Only if they still directly employ people from/have a financial presence in an EU country.

Comment: @Tyler you have *completely* missed the point and you know it. I'm not going to respond to that nonsense. I'll read your comments as simply "I work for a company, or I worked as an individual, that ignores GDPR rules when working with individuals where it applies; please notify the authorities so that sanctions can be made against my business."

Comment: This is literally a duplicate of [your question from 10 months ago.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423817/do-the-cookies-already-work-while-you-just-log-in-on-the-login-screen-of-a-stack)... Start listening to explanations, instead of just making unfounded assumptions.

Comment: _" The default on most websites is to accept all cookies."_ OP, that is ___blatantly false___ and ___illegal___ to do. It's clear that you have a ___very___ limited understanding of how cookies work, so how about instead of assuming all kinds of nonsense, you actually listen to the people that are explaining to you how they work?

Comment: @TylerH _"Only if they still directly employ people from/have a financial presence in an EU country."_ They do. There's plenty of SE employees on LinkedIn that are living in the Netherlands, for example.

Comment: @Cerbrus I often see cookie settings pop ups that say: if you do not click, we take from this your agreement that you accept all cookies (or the like). Also, if you say that this is illegal or not, that is not at all the point of the question. I know that taking all cookies is within GDPR anyway if I know about that, and most pages give you a choice. I have this choice here. I do not speak about GDPR here, but just about whether I have to click on my "Necessary cookies only" choice every time or whether "Necessary cookies only" is the default. What is the default?

Comment: @KevinB The other question is about the same question but then, when you have looged out and could log in instead of clicking on the cookie settings pop up. If I do that, I do not need to agree to any cookie settings. I want to know which cookie settings are saved if I log in instead of clicking on a cookie settings button. If the answer is that logout and login do not play a role, that is also an answer, but it is not a duplicate to this question here. Up to now, nobody has proven what the default settings are while being logged in (this question) or logged out + logging in (that question).

Comment: If you haven’t made a choice, then the choice that is saved is that you haven’t made a choice….

Comment: @KevinB That is alright, I also believe that should be true,  I just want someone to post a proof of that. I have seen too many cookies where you get "all cookies" by default if you do not click at all, and that could even be programmed depending on your login status. And again this should be proven while being logged in (this question) or logged out + logging in (that question), thus, no duplicate.

Comment: To give you a bit more context that "OptanonConsent" cookie in the answer to your previous question is the one that stores your cookie preferences for the site. If you look at that you'll see the object has a "groups" key the value of which has four sub-parts whose values can either be 0 / 1 (essentially a boolean). These 4 correspond directly to the four toggles you get if you choose to customize the preferences. Against your expectations only of them has the value 1 (for the necessary cookies) if you don't confirm your preferences.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Very helpful remark. I was not aware of that. That sounds like an almost 100 % proof for me and could also be an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Only neccessary cookies are accepted by default.**

No visual proof, but coming straight from [staff's <s>mouth</s> keyboard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379047/why-has-there-been-such-a-huge-drop-in-new-visits-since-may-9th-2022-across#comment1265028_379048),

> It's not that people chose not to accept them. More likely, many users took no action. With the reclassification, that cookie can only be stored once they confirm to accept it. But a lot of users who would qualify as "new visits" would be from search engines, where they might have loaded the page, looked at it, and then left without ever interacting with the dialog at all.

(related to the the traffic drop after [recategorization of Google Analytics cookie from "stricly necessary" to "performance cookie"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/378440/241919))

Comment: That, together with the helpful remark of [AbdulAzizBarkat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/14991864/abdul-aziz-barkat) above, is quite enough as an insight.